# Create Highcharts data label formatter that filters the data to display

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I am making use of `highcharts-ng` in my `AngularJS` application, and was wondering if one could filter data making use of the `dataLabels formatter function`?

**I would like to display a `{point.name}` and `{point.value}` only when there is a `{point.value}`.**

I have tried the function below (and some variations), but this does not seem to work:

```
dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    formatter: function () {
        if ('{point.value}') {
            return '{point.name} {point.value}'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could u try like,if($scope.point.value){return '{point.name} {point.value}';}else{return '<div></div>';}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is quite simple.

**I changed my code as follows:**

```
dataLabels: { 
    formatter: function () {
        if (this.point.value) {
            return [this.point.name, this.point.value];
        }
    }
}
```

My question answered on the Highcharts forum:

http://forum.highcharts.com/post128864.html#p128864